# xampp VirtualHost not working in https-vhost.conf

Tags: xampp, httpd.conf, htdocs

when i enter ssv2.localhost in my browser (firefox) it will show htdocs folder in xampp .
i want to it show "htdocs\shopping_project\v2\files" instead and change the $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] in php to "E:\xampp_8_1_6\htdocs\shopping_project\v2\files" .

what's wrong with this ?

this is my hosts file : (system32)

```
127.0.0.1 ssv2.localhost
```

this is my httpd-vhosts.conf : (apache/conf/extra)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName localhost
 DocumentRoot "E:\xampp_8_1_6\htdocs"
 <Directory "E:\xampp_8_1_6\htdocs">
     DirectoryIndex index.php
 </Directory>
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin original.smm1378@gmail.com
     ServerName ssv2.localhost
     DocumentRoot "E:\xampp_8_1_6\htdocs\shopping_project\v2\files"
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     <Directory "E:\xampp_8_1_6\htdocs\shopping_project\v2\files">
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all        
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

also "Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf" is not commented in httpd.conf (apache/conf) and i appended this to end of this file :

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

i restarted xampp and my system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my problem like this :

1 - Add this to first of "apache/conf/extra/**httpd-vhost.conf**" :

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443
```

2 - And Append (end of file) this to "apache/conf/extra/**httpd-vhost.conf**" :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "E:\xampp_8_1_6\htdocs"
    <Directory "E:\xampp_8_1_6\htdocs">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "E:\xampp_8_1_6\htdocs\shopping_project\v2\files"
    ServerName project_one.localhost
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
    <Directory "E:\xampp_8_1_6\htdocs\shopping_project\v2\files">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

3 - Add this to your hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) :

```
127.0.0.1 ssv2.localhost
```

4 - Append this to "apache/conf/httpd.conf" :

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Now you can access to "E:\xampp_8_1_6\htdocs\shopping_project\v2\files" using url "https://ssv2.localhost" .
Hope i helped you .

Comment: "NameVirtualHost" does not have any effect since Apache 2.3.11. It's a deprecated instruction, and can be removed from your configuration file. Reference: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost